# What do you call $\operatorname{diam} (A)^d/\mathcal{L}^d (A)$ for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ convex?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is convex, is there a more or less established name for the quantity $$\operatorname{diam} (A)^d/\mathcal{L}^d (A),$$
where $\mathcal{L}^d (A)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $A$?

The quantity is invariant under isometries and scaling.

For $d=2$ and $A$ a triangle, it is is an extension from the condition preventing angles from being too acute.

Comment: isn't this some kind of measurement of the isotropy/ellipticity? I don't lknow of any name for that quantity, though...